# How to use std::bind with compose2?

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, std

I would like to use a `binary_function` in a `compose2` in C++11 with `std::bind` without using the `boost` library.

**EDIT:** or labmdas.

Suppose I have the following definitions:

```
bool GreaterThanFive(int x) { return x > 5; }

struct DivisibleByN : binary_function<int, int, bool> {
  bool operator()(int x, int n) const { return x % n == 0; }
};
```

Say I want to count the elements of a vector which are greater than 5 and divisible by 3. I can easily combine them with the following:

```
int NumBothCriteria(std::vector<int> v) {
  return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                       __gnu_cxx::compose2(std::logical_and<bool>(),
                                           std::bind2nd(DivisibleByN(), 3),
                                           std::ref(GreaterThanFive)));
}
```

As `bind2nd` is deprecated as of C++11, I would like to move to `std::bind`. I haven't yet figured out why the following is not equivalent (and does not compile).

```
int NumBothCriteria(std::vector<int> v) {
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                       __gnu_cxx::compose2(std::logical_and<bool>(),
                                           std::bind(DivisibleByN(), _1, 3),
                                           std::ref(GreaterThanFive)));
}
```

It gives me the following compile error:

```
no type named 'argument_type' in 'std::_Bind<DivisibleByN *(std::_Placeholder<1>, int)>`
  operator()(const typename _Operation2::argument_type& __x) const
                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

My intuition is that `std::bind` isn't doing something that `std::bind2nd` does, but I'm not sure how to get the `argument_type` typedef back.

[My search came up with three questions.](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=std+bind+compose2) The first uses `bind2nd`, the second uses `boost`, and the third is for C++03. Unfortunately *Effective STL* still uses the `std::bind2nd`.

Comment: Doesn't `std::bind` support composition on its own, so this should work if you replace `__gnu_cxx::compose2` by `std::bind` ?

Comment: @PiotrSkotnicki Yes, you can. Not sure why I initially replied to you that you couldn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just don't use `bind` or `compose2`. You will thank yourself later:

```
int NumBothCriteria(std::vector<int> v) {
  return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                       [](int i){ return i > 5 && i%3 == 0; });
}
```

---

The answer you're looking for is that you can simply use `std::bind` in place of where you're using `__gnu_cxx::compose2`:

```
return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
    std::bind(std::logical_and<bool>(),
        std::bind(DivisibleByN(), _1, 3),
        std::bind(GreaterThanFive, _1)));
```

But that is far more complicated and harder to reason about than just using a lambda.

Comment: My example above is far-simplified from what I'm actually doing.

Comment: @WillBeason Well I'm sure what you're actually doing would benefit from using a lambda too.

Comment: I understand how to do this with lambdas. The point of this question is to learn how to use `std::bind` in scenarios such as this.

Comment: @WillBeason And the answer is to not use `std::bind` in scenarios such as this.

Comment: Nice, I didn't realize they could be nested like that!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to make it work with `std::function`.

```
int NumBothCriteria2(std::vector<int> v) {
  using std::placeholders::_1;
  return std::count_if(v.begin(), v.end(),
                       __gnu_cxx::compose2(std::logical_and<bool>(),
                                           std::function<int(int)>(std::bind(
                                               DivisibleByN(), _1, 3)),
                                           std::ref(GreaterThanFive)));
}
```